# can i use both built in cache & varnsih cache for magento2 at a time?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, varnish

I configured Varnish cache as well as the built in page cache. Now I've got some issues with the cache.

If I disable the built in cache the cache issue is resolved.
So my question is can I use both the built in cache & varnish for my site? Or do I need to use only one of them?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

When you have Varnish cache enabled in Magento 2.x configuration, Page Cache is not active anymore, these are the only two options according to this line of code:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php#L70

Comment: so i can disable built in page cache,it won't effect the performance?

Comment: Only if you disable cache type in cache management you will get performance penalty. As in this case both cache types are going to become disabled, as both of them use the same configuration model:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/Config.php#L224

Comment: i disabled system->cache management->page cache . So automatically Varnish also  won't work ?  i mean if i want to use Varnish i should enable fpc cache type?